# react-redux Reducer doesn't pass the object to the store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have an issue and I could really use some help. I am very new to react and react-redux, so the solution is probably simpler than I might think(I hope so). I have a simple site, that contains Links (from react-router) with names of recipes:

```
class Posts extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchPosts();
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.newPost) {
            this.props.posts.unshift(nextProps.newPost);
        }
    }


    render() {
        const postItems = this.props.posts.map(recipe => (
            <div key={recipe.id}>
                <Link to={`/recipe/id/${recipe.id}`}>{recipe.name}</Link>
            </div>
        ));

        return (

            <Router>
            <div>
                <h1>Well yeah</h1>
                {postItems}
                <Route path={`/recipe/id/:recipeId`} component={Post}/>
            </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
Posts.propTypes = {
    fetchPosts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    posts: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    newPost: PropTypes.object,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    posts: state.posts.items,
    newPost: state.posts.item,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchPosts})(Posts);
```

Now, I also have a component Post, which is supposed to be a single recipe.

```
class Post extends Component {
    static propTypes = {};

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetch();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>Hello{this.props.recipe.name}</div>
        );
    }
}

Post.propTypes = {
    fetch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    recipe: PropTypes.object
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
    fetch: () => {
        dispatch(fetchPostById(ownProps.location.pathname))
    }
});
const mapStateToProps = state => ({

    recipe: state.posts.recipe
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Post);
```

Regardless of what I do, I can't seem to make it work properly. I have an action that fetches the single recipe(I have no problem fetching the list of recipes) and then pass it to the reducer. However, when I put console.log(action.payload) in the case in the reducer, it shows the Object containing the recipe in the console just fine. But when I put {this.props.recipe.name} in Post.js I get an error That this.props.recipe is undefined. Any help is very appreciated. To be sure, I will also post the code of the reducer and the actions.

Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    items: [],
    item: {},
    recipe:{}

};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_RECIPES:
            return {
                ...state,
                items: action.payload
            };
        case NEW_RECIPE:
            return {
                ...state,
                item: action.payload
            };
        case FETCH_RECIPE_ID:
            return{
                ...state,
                recipe:action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

Actions:

```
export const fetchPosts = () => dispatch => {
    fetch('http://192.168.1.3:6996/recipe')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(recipes => dispatch({
            type: FETCH_RECIPES,
            payload: recipes
        }));

};
export const createPost = (postData) => dispatch => {
    fetch('http://192.168.1.3:6996/recipe', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(postData)
    }).then(res => res.json()).then(recipe => dispatch({
        type: NEW_RECIPE,
        payload: recipe
    }))

};
export const fetchPostById= (id) => dispatch => {
    fetch('http://192.168.1.3:6996' + id)
        .then(recipe => recipe.json())
        .then(recipe => dispatch({
        type: FETCH_RECIPE_ID,
        payload: recipe
    }))
};
```

Main reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import postReducer from './postReducer'

export default combineReducers({
    posts: postReducer
});
```

Comment: copy/paste error: `recipe: state.posts.recipe` in `mapStateToProps`

Comment: what do you mean? i find your comment and my code identical?

Comment: fix this place ;)

Comment: I'd love to , but i don't know how

Comment: do you have `posts` in state?

Comment: I do, plus collecting the names of all recipes works and they are also posts.

Comment: update changes 'context'. log props in `componentDidUpdate` and `shouldComponentUpdate() {return true}`

Comment: did you checked props in react dev tools tab? maybe props are updated but view not

Comment: url shouln't contain `'/recipe/'+ id` ? you wrote it fetches fine - it shouldn't with `fetch('http://192.168.1.3:6996' + id)` .... ok, I see `location.pathname'

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by those updates but will look into it tomorrow. It fetchea fine, i get the singular recipe to the reducer, can't seem to get it to Post.js. i thought my problem is with the connect function and/or mapStateToProps

Comment: In your posts and post components add this line inside render `console.log(this.props)` see what you are getting

Comment: I am getting 30 items and empty one- list of the recipes but not the single recipe

Comment: render should be called twice (use log) - if not then updated props don't force rerender (forcing is guaranted for state change) - use `shouldComponentUpdate` to log change/force render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after switching off WebStorm for the night, the site fired up the next morning and worked somewhat fine. I have a problem with the react-router part sill, but I will post different question, so I don't break any rules. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

In this line `recipe: state.posts.recipe` you are implying that there is a posts object in your state that holds your recipe, but in the reducer, I don't see any posts object in your state. try changing it to this line `recipe: state.recipe`

Comment: Yes, sorry, i do. the reducer I show isn't the main one, the main one looks like this:
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import postReducer from './postReducer'

export default combineReducers({
    posts: postReducer
});

Comment: basically yes, i do have to write posts in there

Comment: can you add your other reducer to the post?

Comment: Done. If it is any help I can post the whole thing on github or something..

Comment: is the postReducer the one you posted earlier?

Comment: yes, it is. The post reducer is the one I have showed initially

Comment: Have you configured the Provider in your root component?

Comment: That's the thing - I have! I have almost identical action fetching recipes, only difference being for this action i provide id- so it is twoway, while for the other actions it is always one way